# Google Apps Script - Moderation Queue Reporting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I can't seem to find any documentation on getting a report on pending messages in moderation queue. I want to get a list of all the pending messages for all groups.

The closest I found was on [this page.](https://goo.gl/0mHnMk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google does not have an api for that. the closest api is the one they released last week but is only for reporting group acrivity: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/groups-event-names